# AsFloat convert to string

Tags: delphi, floating-point, format, decimal

Hi
I want to convert "qrysth.Fields[i].AsFloat" to a string so I use the following code:
FormatFloat('0.###############',qrysth.Fields[i].AsFloat)

but I find the result string is 12.000000000000001 while qrysth.Fields[i].AsFloat is 12.00. I know FormatFloat actually not use 12.00 to do the convert, but use an infinite number of binary to do the convert. (like 0.1 in decimal system is 0.1, but it is an infinite number in binary system 0.00011001100...)

Is there other way I could get 12.00 in the case above? or 12.000000000000000 at least?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to convert
>   "qrysth.Fields[i].AsFloat" to a string

Then why not use AsString?

```
qrysth.Fields[i].AsString
```

This will give you the best representation, as long as you're not concerned about the exact width. If you are, use `FormatFloat` with the exact number of digits you need - in other words, if you're looking for `12.00`, use `FormatFloat('##.##', qrysth.Fields[i].AsFloat)`, or even better `CurrToStr`and `AsCurrency`, as they automatically uses two digits after the decimal point.

Comment: Hi where could I know what is this AsFloat acutally doing? How could I know the number it fetched from database?

Comment: Your posts are really confusing. What exactly is your question? You jump from "it doesn't look like I expect" to "what is the real value" to "how does FormatFloat work" to something else. Please edit your original question to explain what it is you really want to know here - it's not useful for you to keep switching the question.

Comment: 1. I want to know how AsFloat fetch data from database. For example, I see the data of the field in database is 12.1300000000, I want to know the value of qrysth.Fields[i].AsFloat, I also want to know why I use OutputDebugString(PChar(FloatToStr(qrysth.Fields[i].AsFloat))); I see 12.13, but when I use FormatFloat('0.###############',qrysth.Fields[i].AsFloat) it is 12.130000000000001 - I want to know how those number convert and got changed.

Comment: 2. Then I want to know whether I can get the data in database 12.1300000000 as a string in delphi 12.130000000000000

Comment: I guess you will have to accept the fact, that a float displayed with 12 decimals doesn't look the same as the same float displayed with 15 decimals. I suggest you have a look at the floating point guide [link](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 5):

If you really get 12.000000000000001, then your field didn't hold exactly 12, so the output is correct. You asked for high precision by putting so many `#` characters in the format. If you don't want it so precise, then use a less precise format string.

Comment: Hi, I think 12 is a bad example. let me take 12.130000000000001 instead of 12.00000000000001. Yes, my field acutally is 12.1300000000 (10 places of decimal in database.) - the reason I see it is 12.13 due to I use the code here: OutputDebugString(PChar(FloatToStr(qrysth.Fields[i].AsFloat)));

Comment: Where could I know what is this AsFloat actually doing?

Comment: Hold the Ctrl key and click on `AsFloat` to have the IDE take you to its implementation. Or set a breakpoint in your code and press F7 to step into the function while debugging.

Comment: How do you *know* your database holds exactly 12.1300000000? That number cannot be represented exactly as any floating-point value, so in converting it to a float, you're *guaranteed* to introduce errors. FloatToStr doesn't necessarily show as much precision as might be available, so it might round the erroneous value *back* to 12.13.

Answer (score 2):

`FormatFloat('0.00',qrysth.Fields[i].AsFloat)` will give '12.00'.

To be able to get '12.000000000000000' you should do the rounding yourself, as there's no loss of precision.

Comment: @spspli - I guess normal rounding, like: `FormatFloat('0.000000000000000', Round(qrysth.Fields[i].AsFloat * 100000000000000) / 100000000000000))`

Answer (score 0):

```
function MyFormatFloat(V: Double): String;
const
  DesiredMinPrec = '0.000000000000000';
  AssumedMaxPrec = '0.#####';
begin
  Result := FormatFloat(DesiredMinPrec, StrToFloat(FormatFloat(AssumedMaxPrec, V)));
end;
```

Comment: Why is your minimum precision *higher* than your maximum precision?

Comment: Haha, I doubted the naming too, hence the edit. But this is my intention: The assumed precision applies to the V parameter. So in this case a maximum of 6 digits in V are evaluated. The desired precision applies to the result of the function which returns a minimum of 16 digits. The function could also have been named TruncFloat. ;)